# Java swing drop down selection listener

Tags: java, swing, events, listener

I have a JCombobox with the large list of items.  Upon selecting an Item, I need something done.
I tried with actionListener and with itemListner

```
myComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            String selection = (String)myComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("Selected: "+selection ) ;
        }
    }
});
```

With Action listener, I tried the same thing

The problem, I am facing is this
When user rolls through the open drop down he inadvertently keep selecting each item he does not need.  (or if uses the mouse wheel, etc...).
So, I want to be able to catch ONLY that selection that user makes.
How can it be done ?

Comment: Your code is a correct way to do it. It only select one element I checked it. May be your problem doesnt contain in this.

Comment: Blasanka, please use Keyboard to scroll through the list.  You will see that that if you need to actually select 100th item in the list, the code "thinks" that you are selecting each of all the preceding 99 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem, I am facing is this When user rolls through the open drop down he inadvertently keep selecting each item he does not need.

You can prevent the listener from firing by using:

```
comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
```

For example:

```
/*
    This works on non editable combo boxes
*/
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ComboBoxAction extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public ComboBoxAction()
    {
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.addActionListener( this );

        comboBox.addItem( "Item 1" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 2" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 3" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 4" );

        //  This prevents action events from being fired when the
        //  up/down arrow keys are used on the dropdown menu

        comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);

        getContentPane().add( comboBox );
        getContentPane().add( new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println( e.getModifiers() );

        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        System.out.println( comboBox.getSelectedItem() );

        //  make sure popup is closed when 'isTableCellEditor' is used

//      comboBox.hidePopup();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ComboBoxAction frame = new ComboBoxAction();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried your example as a stand alone, and it works perfectly. 
But, when I incorporate it into my system, I get the output twice - that is that ActionPerformed is done twice .. or seems this way ?

Comment: Hallelujah !! 
I resolved that "double" action by using ItemListener, instead of ActionListener .. well and checking for itemEvent  being "selected" and not DESELECTED.
This resolved it.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> The problem, I am facing is this When user rolls through the open drop
>   down he inadvertently keep selecting each item he does not need.

Reason for that is, when press arraw up and down it is also state change. So my solution is you can add `keyTyped` `actionListener`. Then you can get the code for arrow key and check for arraw press. Like below:

```
myComboBox.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        String x = String.valueOf(myComboBox.getSelectedItem());

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 40) {
            System.out.println(x);
            //System.out.println(evt.getKeyCode());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use ActionListeners, like this:

```
combo.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: Akash.  Thanks for the reply.  I did use.  I mentioned it in the post.
You see the problem, when drop down has 10 items in the list and user wants to pick item at position "7". He can do 2 things:
 1)  - he navigates directly to item "7", then there is NO PROBLEM.
 2) - user "rolls" through  the list from beginning to that #7, using the 
        mouse wheel or keyboard arrows.  In this case, actionListener sees that he selects every single item 1, 2,3, ..7.  I want the program to "Ignore"  the 1..6 items.

Comment: Dima , you  can use e.getStateChange()  to get selected item to ignore the items.

Comment: I tried it.  I have it in my original post.  I am checking if state is SELECTED.  
But, it still keeps thinking that all the previous items were selected as well, not ignoring them.  This is what I do:  if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
Is it not correct ?